# Considerations for projecting enterprise database to a new coordinate system

Tags: coordinate-system, enterprise-geodatabase, utm, state-plane

I currently maintain an enterprise geodatabase where the data is projected in a state plane coordinate system. Recently the data has extended past state boundaries. The data units are in feet and polylines do contain M values. I am concerned measures and GIS lengths(lengths are very important in the database) could become skewed as GIS data extends farther away from state boundaries.

In order to address this issue I am considering projecting the data into a new database using a non-state, regionally based coordinate system such as an UTM Zone.

My questions are following:

- Would if be acceptable to just leave the data in state plane knowing measures are maintained?
- Are there any issues with projecting from state plane into UTM Zone?(I have never done this for an SDE database)
  Could English units to Metric Units be a concern?
- Any suggestion or tips regarding this type of conversion?

Comment: Do you have a requirement saying the M values must match the polyline length?

Comment: No shape and measure lengths are separate and independent values. Polyline measures are based on survey collection and linear referencing. All my reporting is done via GIS shape length because I don't have measures for all features.

Comment: My major concern would be change in shape length when projected into new system.

Comment: There isn't anything Esri-specific about this question, *per se*. If you [Edit] the question to provide details of *which* state plane, and your actual data envelope, you might get less *opinion-based* answers.

Comment: Specifically, what coordinate system are you currently using?

Comment: Delaware State Plane. I would like to move to UTM zone 18